# Cognos - Showing every month on x-axis when some months don't have values

Tags: cognos, cognos-10, cognos-bi

Let me first say I am very new to Cognos and have mainly learned by just manipulating items within active reports. I am having an issue with creating a graph that acts like a time series. I want it to display every month (with multiple values in some months and none in others). I want to visually see gaps between data points (ex: we order products every 3 months starting in January, so we should see gaps in the months we do not order products - like February and March). 
I have tried changing the label control to manual and setting display frequency to 1. However, I think my issue is that there is not any data within certain months.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are correct in that your problem is lack of data. A standard inner join will drop rows where there is not a corresponding row in both tables, resulting in gaps.

There are two solutions available:

1. Use a union to create "dummy" records for each date
2. Manually specify an outer join between the date table and the table containing the rest of information

Since the first technique is the most common, I'll outline the basic steps for it here.

1. Create a new query
2. Add your month data item to the query
3. Create a 'dummy' data item for your measure. Use 0 for its expression.
4. If there is a date range filter in the main query apply it here
5. Create a union
6. Drag over your new query into the union
7. Drag over your original query into the union
8. Pull in the date and measure data items into the union query
9. Set the *Aggregate Function* property of the measure to *Total*
10. Use the union query as the source for your chart

For every month with measure data you will have two rows, one with the measure amount and one with 0. The two rows will be combined by the auto-group and summarize function. The measures will be added together. Anything added to 0 will end up as the original amount.

For months with no measure data, there will only be the 'dummy' row with 0 for the measure and it will be represented in your chart.

Comment: Maybe I'm not understanding the solution, but it doesn't seem to be working. Each row in my data set contains a date (col 1) and a cost (col2) (there are other columns, but not too important). So, all dates exist in my data already, and I think I need to add in rows to get months that don't exist. I'm also having an issue with using total; it will add all my costs together for a single month (I want to see every cost). I am also having issues with the union query. It seems I can't do the union unless every data item is the same for both queries. How would you do the outer join (teradata sql)?

Comment: You say "all dates exist in my data already". If this is true then you shouldn't have any problem. There would not be any gaps. I guess I don't understand your problem.

Comment: I am looking for something like this: http://image.tutorvista.com/cms/images/39/scatter-plot1.JPG. I want to see gaps between my months in the chart like in the picture. When I try to use your solution, it seems to be only giving me back the normal month since it is not creating new rows. Sorry if this sounds confusing.

Comment: You should be able to use my instructions. I've amended them to use 'month' instead of date field.

Comment: Sorry for a very late reply. I was able to get all the months to appear by adding some code in SQL to make zeroes appear for months with no previous data, then I made the points transparent. I am now having the issue where my charts will not generate for any graph that has more than 2000 points. Do you know of any way to change this?

Comment: It sounds like you used SQL to do what I was suggesting using unions. I'm not sure how to get around a 2000 point limit. Cognos' charting capabilities are pretty limited, in my experience.